# Can I Specify Multiple botium.json file in botium.spec,js file to tell botium that i want to run multiple test suite?

Tags: automation, chatbot

```
    Currenly i am using single botium.json file to run my chatbot test suite. Is there any way where can i specify multiple botium.json file to run my test suite in one by one and multiple test suite same like I can change my convo directory using spec file. if so Please help. I have tried below 2 options
```

1.I have created insuranceBotium.json file and also other botium configuratino files. how can I write code to execute all test suite using all config file

2. I have tried below code.

```
  const BotiumBindings = require('botium-bindings')
  const BotDriver = require('botium-core').BotDriver
  const Capabilities = require('botium-core').Capabilities
  const Source = require('botium-core').Source
  const driver = new BotDriver()
    .setCapability(Capabilities.PROJECTNAME, 'core-CreateNewConversation')
    .setCapability(Capabilities.CONTAINERMODE , 'watson')
    .setCapability(Capabilities.WATSON_APIKEY, '')
    .setCapability(Capabilities.WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID, '')
    .setCapability(Capabilities.WATSON_URL, 'https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api')
    .setCapability(Capabilities.WATSON_COPY_WORKSPACE, false)


  const bb = new BotiumBindings({botiumConfig:driver , convodirs: [ './spec/convo/Insurance' ]})
  BotiumBindings.helper.mocha().setupMochaTestSuite({ bb })
```

Comment: Are you using Botium Bindings, Botium CLI or Botium Box ?

Comment: I am using Botium Bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to set the BOTIUM_CONFIG environment variable in your botium.spec.js:

```
const BotiumBindings = require('botium-bindings')

process.env.BOTIUM_CONFIG='./botium-1.json'
const bb = new BotiumBindings({convodirs: ['./spec/convo/Insurance' ]})
BotiumBindings.helper.mocha().setupMochaTestSuite({ bb })
```

You can have multiple *.spec.js files, each pointing to another botium.json and another set of convo files.